# Run a shell script when a database record is written to postgres

Tags: postgresql

Is there some mechanism in postgres that can fire off a shell script when a database record is written? I can write a script to just monitor the database and table but before doing that I wanted to make sure there wasn't a "better" way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write a trigger function using [PL/sh](https://github.com/petere/plsh).  That's what it's for.

Comment: for other later on ... Used the PL Python trigger in postgres to write to a queue. I then have a script that works with the queue. This was a better way to handle it then letting the DB script drive any real work.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably use rule or trigger and start your shell script for whatever PL that supports it, but I think the better way is to use it for sending notification and monitor it from a separate process.

Comment: Yeah, one shell script per row just doesn't sound like a good idea.