# How to detect and respond to a database change (INSERT) from a django project?

Tags: django, postgresql

I am setting up our project to integrate with a shipping platform called Endicia which has the ability to insert new rows into our database when a package is shipped.

How can I detect from python when a new row has been inserted?

My solution for now would be to query the DB every 30 seconds or so for new rows... is there another solution to send a signal from postgres to python?

Comment: Some ideas [here](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/How-to-get-a-signal-from-the-database-when-a-INSERT-INTO-is-done-tp5521511p5521949.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd set up a [custom command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) that is run by the `manage.py` file.

You'd put it in `yourapp/management/commands/' folder. Make sure to add an **init**.py file to both the management and commands folder or the command won't work. Then you create the code for the custom command.

Then, see this [related question about running a shell script when changes are made to a postgres database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7902348/run-a-shell-script-when-a-database-record-is-written-to-postgres). The answer there was to use [PL/sh](https://github.com/petere/plsh). You'll need to figure that part out on your own, but basically however you do it, the end result is that the script should call something like `/path/to/app/manage.py command_name`