# How to execute a python script form a stored procedure in PostgreSql?

Tags: postgresql

I want to execute a python script form a stored procedure in PostgreSql

I want something like this:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER executePython
  AFTER INSERT ON mytable
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
  SYSTEM('python MyApp');
  END;
```

Anyone can help me, please?

Answer (score 9):

Are you able to install extensions? If so, you can use the [the `PL/Python` extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpython-funcs.html)

```
CREATE FUNCTION callMyApp()
RETURNS VOID
AS $$
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/python', '/path/to/MyApp'])
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;

CREATE TRIGGER executePython 
AFTER INSERT ON messages 
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE callMyApp();
```

Note that this will run as the postgres user, so there may be permission issues.

There's also an extension called [`PL/SH`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpython-funcs.html), which might be of use, but doesn't appear to be an official package.

```
CREATE FUNCTION executePython()
RETURNS VOID
AS $$
#!/bin/sh
python /path/to/MyApp
$$
LANGUAGE plsh;
```

[This blog post](http://www.subdimension.co.uk/2012/12/19/PostgreSQL_triggers_in_plpython.html) might be of interest to you, as well.

Also, this is nearly a duplicate of this thread entitled [Run a shell script when a database record is written to postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7902348/run-a-shell-script-when-a-database-record-is-written-to-postgres).

(Note: I haven't tested any of this code.)